# Create a goal with a funnel using regex?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a goal with a funnel.

I'm trying to use a regular expression for my goal that means that my URL can have any word after it, followed by /basket/thank-you:

```
.*/basket/thank-you
```

I then have a funnel set up with pages set up with the regular expression in them:

```
.*/basket/step-1
.*/basket/step-2
.*/basket/step-3
```

But it's not being tracked. Have I set it up correctly with regular expressions? Should the regular expression also be used in the funnel?